# Is $X_{i}$ a martingale, submartingale, or supermartingale?

Tags: probability, model-selection, stochastic-processes, marginal-distribution

Let $X_{i}$, $i=0,1,\cdots$ be a sequence of random variables generated by $X_{i+1}=\rho X_{i}+W_{i}$, where $\rho$ is constant and $W_{i}$ are i.i.d random variables. Suppose $X_{0}$ is independent of $W_{i}$. Is $X_{i}$ a martingale, submartingale, or supermartingale?

Comment: Did you try to check your random variable against the definitions for sub-super-martingale?

Comment: What is the filtration? $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ or $\mathscr{G}_n=\sigma(W_1,\dots,W_n)$?

Comment: @Zen . my filtration is $\mathcal F_{n}=\sigma(X_{1},...,X_{n})$

Comment: Also, for $n\geq 1$, $X_n=\rho^n X_0 + \rho^{n-1}W_0+\rho^{n-2}W_1 +\dots+W_{n-1}$.

Comment: @Zen . I think yes

Comment: @zen. yes it is true

Comment: Consider the following three cases:  $\rho = 1, \text{E}W = 1$, $\rho = 0.5, \text{E}W = 0$, $\rho = 0, \text{E}W = 0$. In which of these cases, if any, does $\text{E}(X_{n+1}|X_1, \dots, X_n) = X_n$?  And similarly for the sub - and super- martingale conditions.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $X_{i+1}=\rho X_i+W_{i+1}$? As in $AR(1)$ process?

Comment: @mpiktas.I chek the Question and it was  true

Comment: @zen. thank you for answering this question and your answer is really clear and good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$, since
$$X_n = \rho^nX_0 + \rho^{n-1}W_0 + \rho^{n-2}W_1 + \dots + W_{n-1} \, ,$$
it follows that $W_n$ is independent of $X_1, \dots,X_n$, because they are functions of $X_0,W_0,W_1,\dots,W_{n-1}$ only and the $W_i$'s and $X_0$ are independent. Therefore, defining $\mathscr{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, we have almost surely
$$
  \mathrm{E}[X_{n+1}\mid\mathscr{F}_n] = \rho\,\mathrm{E}[X_n\mid\mathscr{F}_n]  +\mathrm{E}[W_n\mid\mathscr{F}_n] = \rho\,X_n + \mathrm{E}[W_n] \, .
$$
From here we need to know more about the value of $\rho$ and the distributions of $X_0$ and the $W_i$'s.

For example, if $\mathrm{E}[W_i]=0$, for every $i\geq 1$, and $\rho=1$, then $\{(X_i,\mathscr{F}_i)\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a martingale.

If $\mathrm{E}[W_i]\leq 0$, for every $i\geq 1$, and $\rho=1$, then $\{(X_i,\mathscr{F}_i)\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a supermartingale.

If $X_0$ and the $W_i$'s are almost surely positive, and $\rho>1$, then $\{(X_i,\mathscr{F}_i)\}_{i\geq 1}$ is a submartingale.

Comment: If $\text{E}W = 0$... what is $\text{E}X_{n+1}$ if $\rho = 0.5$ and $X_n = -1$?  What if $\rho = 0.5$ and $X_n = 1$?

Comment: After you've observed it, it's not.  The point is that if $\rho \neq 1$, $\text{E}X_{n+1}$ is not always $\leq$ or $\geq$ $X_n$.

Comment: No, it's not.  It's a property that holds on almost all sample paths, which are of course realizations in some abstract sense of the word.  To return to my original point, though, and simplify it some:  does the super/sub/just plain martingale property hold if $\rho = 0.5$?  The answer is obviously no, because for $X_n < 0$, $\text{E}X_{n+1} > X_n$, and conversely for $X_n > 0$.  Extending that to other values of $\rho$ should make it clear that your last sentence isn't correct (although it would be if $X_i \geq 0 \forall i$.)

Comment: I should indeed retract that "No it's not", that was not really conveying what I meant.  (Sort of rushed here, my apologies, and  I should know better than to rush a comment or an answer by now.)  I agree that more information from the OP would be very helpful.

Comment: No problem. We're fine. We're probably using the words with slightly different meanings. Thank you for your comments.